# Htaccess rule to access php files using different extensions

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm working on this project which requires all php files extension to be changed.
So, for example, if the name of a php file is **example.php** ..I should be able to access it in this way **example.anyextension**.

I'm confident it could be done via htaccess.
I could do it for a single file.
But how would I do it for all the files ?

I have written this code for a single file so far :-

```
RewriteRule ^login/?$ login.php
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Have you tried something like `RewriteRule ^(.+)\.[^.]+$ $1.php`? (untested)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, I tried this and it worked.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.zig$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

It would convert **eample.php** to **example.zig**.